# Changing VBA macro code to change number

Tags: excel, vba

What I'm trying to do is increment number and then loop subtract the first `2` digits by `1` 
and then increment the rest until the first `2` digits = `0`

So I have `M201001` would become `m191002` and next would be `m181003` until `m011020`

Comment: Not sure this is on topic here, but if you want help with a macro you're working on, it might be useful to include it in your question `;-)`

Comment: Are you sure the VB.NET tag is correct?  VB.NET != VB (or VBA).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you'll need to do is break up your value into 3 using `left`, `mid` and `right` functions.

Then do the looping as you require it. I'm trying it out myself so I'll update my answer once I've done so.

**Added Code:**

```
Sub Testing()

    Dim myIn As String
    myIn = "M201001"

    Dim myLeft As String
    Dim myMid As Integer, myRight As Integer, i As Integer
    Dim myOut As String
    myLeft = Left(myIn, 1)
    myMid = CInt(Mid(myIn, 2, 2))
    myRight = CInt(Right(myIn, 4))
    myOut = myLeft & Format(myMid, "00") & Format(myRight, "0000")
    i = 0

    Debug.Print "IN:        " & myIn
    Debug.Print "BROKEN UP: " & myOut

    Do Until myMid = -1
        Debug.Print "ITERATION " & Format(i, "00") & ": " & myLeft & Format(myMid, "00") & Format(myRight, "0000")

        myMid = myMid - 1
        myRight = myRight + 1
        myOut = myLeft & Format(myMid, "00") & Format(myRight, "0000")
        i = i + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

If you need any explanation please ask. I will be happy to explain.

Comment: thats awesome so beyond my capability!
it even calculates it within the macro which i guess is what debug print is and using ITERATION well now got that i need to place it to where it puts those in a sheet which im gona play arround with it and post it up here

Comment: I had to post a new question since the rules of the site state to do so which is on this page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14996655/changing-vba-macro-code-to-change-number-part-2 was trying to get it to work almost there

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Function GetNextNumber(n As String) As Variant
    ' Validate input
    If Len(n) <> 7 Then
        GetNextNumber = xlErrNum
        Exit Function
    ElseIf Left$(n, 1) <> "M" Then
        GetNextNumber = CVErr(xlErrNum)
        Exit Function
    End If

    GetNextNumber = Left$(n, 1) & Format(val(Mid$(n, 2)) - 9999, "000000")

End Function
```

Test using this

```
Sub demo()
    Dim n As Variant

    n = "M201001"
    Debug.Print n
    Do
        n = GetNextNumber(CStr(n))
        If IsError(n) Then Exit Sub
        Debug.Print n
    Loop Until val(Mid$(n, 2)) <= 19999
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for your help with that but i need it to separate the number like the macro bellow

Comment: I had to post a new question since the rules of the site state to do so which is on this page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14996655/changing-vba-macro-code-to-change-number-part-2